# Why doesn't the contex value get updated until the state's value does?

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, next.js

I'm using a context to generate tab like elements:

```
import { createContext } from "react"

let TABS = createContext({
    tabs:[],
    setTabs:(tab)=>{
        const allTabs = this.tabs;
        this.tabs = [...allTabs,tab];
    }
});

export default TABS;
```

And I'm using the sidebar menu items to add to the tabs. Also I'm using a state to change sidebar menu's content:

```
const DUMMY_DATA = {
  "paymentAndRecieve": {
    actions: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: <IntlMessages id="sidebar.paymentAndRecieve.actions.recieve" />,
        url: "/paymentAndRecieve/actions/recieve",
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: <IntlMessages id="sidebar.paymentAndRecieve.actions.pay" />,
        url: "/paymentAndRecieve/actions/pay",
      },
    ],
    lists: [
      {
        id: 4,
        title: <IntlMessages id="sidebar.paymentAndRecieve.actions.recieve" />,
        url: "/paymentAndRecieve/lists/recieve",
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: <IntlMessages id="sidebar.paymentAndRecieve.actions.pay" />,
        url: "/paymentAndRecieve/lists/pay",
      },
    ],
  },
  "accounting": {
    actions: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: <IntlMessages id="sidebar.accounting.actions.recieve" />,
        url: "/paymentAndRecieve/actions/recieve",
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: <IntlMessages id="sidebar.accounting.actions.pay" />,
        url: "/paymentAndRecieve/actions/pay",
      },
    ],
    lists: [
      {
        id: 4,
        title: <IntlMessages id="sidebar.accounting.actions.recieve" />,
        url: "/paymentAndRecieve/lists/recieve",
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: <IntlMessages id="sidebar.accounting.actions.pay" />,
        url: "/paymentAndRecieve/lists/pay",
      },
    ],
  },
};
const Panel = Collapse.Panel;

const SubMenu = Menu.SubMenu;
const MenuItemGroup = Menu.ItemGroup;

const SidebarContent = ({ sidebarCollapsed, setSidebarCollapsed }) => {
  const { navStyle, themeType } = useSelector(({ settings }) => settings);
  const pathname = useSelector(({ common }) => common.pathname);
  const { tabs, setTabs } = useContext(TABS);
  const [category, setCategory] = useState([]);
  const history = useHistory();

  

  function addTab({ title, id, url }) {
    
    let tabLength = tabs.find((tab) => tab.id === id);
    if (!tabLength) {
     
      setTabs([...tabs  ,{title: title, id: id, url: url }]);
    }
    console.log(tabs)
    history.push(url);
  }
  function changeCategory(id) {
    const actions = (
      <MenuItemGroup key="actions" className="gx-menu-group">
        <Collapse accordion>
          <Panel showArrow={false} header="عملیات">
            {DUMMY_DATA[id].actions.map((option) => {
              return (
                <Menu.Item key={option.id}>
                  <button
                    className={classes.link_option}
                    onClick={() => {
                      addTab(option);
                    }}
                  >
                    {option.title}
                  </button>
                </Menu.Item>
              );
            })}
          </Panel>
        </Collapse>
      </MenuItemGroup>
    );
    const lists = (
      <MenuItemGroup key="lists" className="gx-menu-group">
        <Collapse accordion>
          <Panel showArrow={false} header="فهرست ها">
            {DUMMY_DATA[id].lists.map((option) => {
              return (
                <Menu.Item key={option.id}>
                  <button
                    className={classes.link_option}
                    onClick={() => {
                      addTab(option);
                    }}
                  >
                    {option.title}
                  </button>
                </Menu.Item>
              );
            })}
          </Panel>
        </Collapse>
      </MenuItemGroup>
    );
    setCategory([actions, lists]);
  }
  
  const getNoHeaderClass = (navStyle) => {
    if (
      navStyle === NAV_STYLE_NO_HEADER_MINI_SIDEBAR ||
      navStyle === NAV_STYLE_NO_HEADER_EXPANDED_SIDEBAR
    ) {
      return "gx-no-header-notifications";
    }
    return "";
  };

  const selectedKeys = pathname.substr(1);
  const defaultOpenKeys = selectedKeys.split("/")[1];

  console.log(category);
  return (
    <>
      <SidebarLogo
        sidebarCollapsed={sidebarCollapsed}
        setSidebarCollapsed={setSidebarCollapsed}
      />
      <div className="gx-sidebar-content">
        <div
          className={`gx-sidebar-notifications ${getNoHeaderClass(navStyle)}`}
        >
          <UserProfile />
          <AppsNavigation />
        </div>
        <CustomScrollbars
          className={`gx-layout-sider-scrollbar ${classes.scrollbar}`}
        >
          <Menu
            defaultOpenKeys={[defaultOpenKeys]}
            selectedKeys={[selectedKeys]}
            theme={themeType === THEME_TYPE_LITE ? "lite" : "dark"}
            mode="inline"
          >
              {category}

          </Menu>
        </CustomScrollbars>
        <div className={classes.categories}>
          <button
            className={classes.category}
            onClick={() => {
              changeCategory("accounting");
            }}
          >
            accounting
          </button>
          <button
            className={classes.category}
            onClick={() => {
              changeCategory("paymentAndRecieve");
            }}
          >
            Payment & Receive
          </button>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default React.memo(SidebarContent);
```

and this is how I show my tabs:

```
const OpentTabs = () => {
  const history= useHistory();
  const {tabs,setTabs} = useContext(TABS);


  function removeTab(id){
    const currentTab = tabs.find(tab=> tab.id===id);
    setTabs(tabs.filter(tab => tab.id!== id));
    if(currentTab.url===window.location.pathname){
      console.log(window.location.pathname === tabs[tabs.length-1].url? tabs[tabs.length-2].url:tabs[tabs.length-1].url);
      if(tabs.length>1){
        history.push(window.location.pathname === tabs[tabs.length-1].url? tabs[tabs.length-2].url:tabs[tabs.length-1].url);
      }else{
        history.push('/home')
      }

    }
    
  }


  const  tabList = tabs.map((tab) => {
    return (
      <li
        key={tab.id}
        className={classes.tab}
      >
        
        <i className="icon icon-close" onClick={()=>{removeTab(tab.id)}}></i> 
        <NavLink id={tab.id} to={tab.url} className={isActive =>
          isActive
            ? classes.active
            : classes.inactive}>
          {tab.title}
        </NavLink>
      </li>
    );
  });

  return <ul className={classes.ul}>{tabList}</ul>;
};

export default OpentTabs;
```

But my problem is that when I open a new tab the context value is emptied and the filled therefor it doesn't keep the previously opened tabs, That's until a new category is chosen, then it will keep the previous tabs and open a new one But even then it will only change the last tab. what should I do?

have tried using another state and pouring that state into the context but it just made the webpage to breakdown.